# Angular2 components reloading

Tags: typescript, angular, loader, systemjs

I met a problem here, when I upload a Angular 2 component to server and then import it using `System.import('../my-component')`, it works well.

But If I update the component(template) and upload it again, it won't be imported again. Is it because I have imported it before?

Any one could tell me how to reload an existing `component/module/ts` file ?

Comment: try keeping your typescript compiler in watch mode while you do the import again. `npm run tsc:w`

Comment: @candidJ, I think it's none of business with typescript compilation, it's related to module loader which doesn't import an existing module again.